# How to recover from too many collections in a replica set?

Tags: mongodb

My MongoDB replica set of three servers is in a state such that the primary is up, but both secondaries are down.

Restarting the secondaries, they both report "10081 too many namespaces/collections" in the error logs and the servers are dead.

From my primary I am able to delete collections, but restarting the secondaries still reports the error.

How can I clean up my mess from the primary, and allow the secondaries to start?

UPDATE:

I emptied the data directories for both secondaries and restarted them to cause a fresh sync from the primary. This appears to work, except at some point during the sync they receive some kind of corrupt index warning, and crash again.

The error I get is "hashtable namespace index max chain reached:1335" followed by "no NamespaceDetails for index: {  }"

This error now occurs on the primary, including when running "mongod --repair"

How can I recover from this namespace error?

Answer (score 2):

To put it politely: you are in trouble. Your exact problem is that you would have to increase the namespace size, which can not be increased dynamically ([yet](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-385)).

Here is what you need to do:

1. Shut down mongod on your primary and your secondaries.
2. Ensure you have at least as much free disk space as your MongoDB needs now (actually, you need less, but it's a good rule of thumb)
3. Create a dump from the datafiles of the primary using
   `mongodump --dbpath /path/to/datafiles --journal --dumpDbUsersAndRoles`
4. Delete the content of your dbpath directory on the primary and the secondaries.
5. Change the [nsSize](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/#storage.nsSize) parameter in mongod.conf according to the documentation on all nodes.
6. Restart your nodes, recreate the replica set.
7. Restore your data to the primary using [mongorestore](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongorestore/)(don't use the `--dbpath` option, connect to the running instance!)

If in doubt on any of these steps, please consult (read "hire") a specialist.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I can't run `mongodump`. Well, I can but it fails as soon as it hits the problem collection.

Comment: Have you run mongodump against the datafiles or the running instance? And have you tried to run mongodump with the `--repair` option?

Comment: instance can't be run, so no. Yes also tried with repair.

Comment: Thought primary is still up. Maybe we should [chat about that](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63282/mongodb-nssize-problem).